# How to bind to the TextElement.Foreground of a button?

Tags: wpf, binding

I have the following button:

```
<Button>
        <Path Stroke="???" Data="M0,5 H10 M5,5 V10Z" />
</Button>
```

I want to bind the Stroke property of the path to the TextElement.Foreground property of the underlying content presenter of the button. With this it has always the same color as any text in any other button.

What I tried:

```
{Binding Path=(TextElement.Foreground), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}
```

What I got is a XamlParseException caused by a System.IO.FileNotFoundException. It says that the assembly RibbonControlsLibrary could not be found. What is my fault? Is there an other way?

Regards, Yggdrasil

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can answer my own question.

First of all what I needed was:

```
{Binding Path=(TextElement.Foreground), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentPresenter}}
```

But I also got the exception. I saw that somehow my project had a reference to RibbonControlsLibrary. I deleted this and got no exception. The interesting thing is, that if I use an explicit color I got no exception.

The other thing I found out is, in the Windows 7 standard theme I could use `{Binding Foreground, ElementName=button}` because it was implemented like this:

```
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
       <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
</Trigger>
```

In Windows 8 this does not work because the implemntation was changed to:

```
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
       [...]
       <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}" TargetName="contentPresenter" />
</Trigger>
```

Regards,Yggdrasil.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}` instead of `RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}`.

`RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}` also works.

I think the reason what you have done didn't work is because the path isn't in the template of the button. it's its Content.

Comment: If you remove this Binding and sets the Stroke to some color, you don't get this exception?